# Swagger-ui doesn't generate correct query string

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm trying to create a asp.net core web api to accept a query string of a dictionary with a custom type as a value (e.g. Dictionary<string, User>).
I have generated the default web-api example using visual studio 2019 and have the following:

- Installed Swashbuckle 5.5.0 and setup the required SwaggerGen, UseSwagger, SwaggerUi calls

```
public class User 
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromQuery] Dictionary<string, User> users)
{
  // do something
}
```

Running through swagger-ui and selecting the 'try-out' option produces the following query string:

```
https://localhost:44396/WeatherForecast?additionalProp1[name]=string
```

In the debugger produces:
[image: debugger]

If I change the query string to:

```
https://localhost:44396/WeatherForecast?users[additionalProp1].name=string
```

I get the Value in the dictionary being set:
[image: debugger part 2]

So the question is - what do I need to tell Swagger to create the correct query string in swagger-ui?